# Проблема с text-stroke и Montserrat

Tags: html, css, шрифты

У меня стоит задача сделать задним планом увеличенный прозрачный текст заголовка с обводкой. Шрифт Montserrat. 
**Сделал, но результат конечно насмешил**.[image: Montserrat]

Первая мысль: ясно, это шрифт с засечками, попробую без них.
**font-family: sans-serif;**
[image: sans-serif]

Прекрасно, но мне все равно неприятно, что я не до конца выполнил задачу - использовал не тот шрифт. Думаю: надо бы проверить как работает это свойство с другими шрифтами с засечками, может баг в самом Montserrat`е.
**font-family: serif;**
[image: serif]
И все нормально. Никаких заступов и непонятных треугольничков. Можете подсказать можно ли вообще что-либо в свойствах самого Montserrat, чтобы обводка работала корректно и, если можно, то как.

```css
.gain__decor-title {
    pointer-events: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 3%;
    right: 3%;

    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 166px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 202px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    background-clip: text;    
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример (вариант с `box-shadow`)

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.gain__decor-title {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 166px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 202px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="gain__decor-title">Что ты получишь</h2>
```