Исправление шрифт при подключении
В React+Vite подключаю шрифт
файл подключения выглядит следующим образом.
_importFonts.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff") format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.woff") format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff") format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("../assets/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.woff2") format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}

импортирую в основйной файл стилей
index.css
@import url("./_importFonts.scss");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

использую вместе с tailwind
хочу сделать текст с обводкой, но любой подключеный шрифт ломает текст,
как мне это исправить, и скажите как правильно подключать шрифты.


Уже был такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465710/

Вообще рекомендуют использовать статический шрифт https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/4212#issuecomment-1012006441, но кажется у вас уже он и есть.
